# How can I make absolutely positioned transformed elements dynamic?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/uL4eeuvf/

```css
.featured-page div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: -18px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-page">
  <a href="/testpage">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=250%C3%97250&w=250&h=250">
    <div>Testing</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

My issue is that I would like the text within the div to be dynamic, but modifying the text moves the div out of position. For example, changing the text to "testing page" makes it fly away from the edge of the parent div. Is it possible to set it up so that adding more text just extends the length of the child div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property to position the element from the top left edge :

```css
.featured-page {
  position: relative;
}
.featured-page div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-page col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 no-padding">
  <a href="/testpage">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=250%C3%97250&w=250&h=250">
    <div>Testing blah</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note that:

- I also added `position:relative;` to the parent div so the child is position relative to `.featured-page` and not the window.
- I added `white-space:nowrap` so the text stays on one line (thx [@Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552357/how-can-i-make-absolutely-positioned-transformed-elements-dynamic/36552446?noredirect=1#comment60705460_36552446))
- You can also use `rotate(-90deg)` rather than `rotate(270deg)` as commented by [@Mr.alien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552357/how-can-i-make-absolutely-positioned-transformed-elements-dynamic/36552446?noredirect=1#comment60705575_36552446).

Comment: idk @Paulie_D, maybe OP wants it on several lines?

Comment: Well the requirement was to extend the "length"...IDK.

Comment: Late to the party as always, btw, he can use `-90deg` instead of going till `270`